# AppleScript to click buttons and close tabs

Tags: safari, applescript, search, click

Im not really familiar with applescript (using C/Python/Pacsal atm). So far did the autoclicker for my WoW ore prospection.

I would like to use the script on safari to click the link with name "1st Text goes here" to open new tab, then click other link "2nd Text goes here" and then close tab. (repeat n number of times)

My knowledges led me to the following.

```
tell application "Safari"

end tell
```

Hints and tips are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these links are going to be in the same place every time, I'd try Watch Me Do (open up Automator, tell it you want an application. There are lots of built-in actions in the "Internet" subsection of Library, `Website Popup` looks promising for you.

If that all fails or you want something quick and dirty, pressing the Record button up at the top right will record your screen and keyboard inputs, as well as events for you. You could just code a loop to run the generated code over and over again N times, but be warned that Watch Me Do (the thing activated by record) is only screen scraping. If those links ever move or your window isn't in the same place, the script will bomb, probably clicking on things you don't want it to at all, so be careful!

Comment: i got it, but the all stuff is about looking for the text on page, its coordinates change after each cycle :/

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do? Do you need to go to a given URL every time, or click a given button on a web page or in a different application?

Comment: press two links in sequence, links have specific names(not url), that dont change after cycle. then close opened tabs. repeat

Comment: Sounds like this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369073/controlling-browser-using-python     Is there a reason you're using AppleScript rather than python or java?

Comment: I can't install python on my mac or make c work outside the terminal with safari, know this is stupid but thats how it is :D thnx for the link, willing to + it, but have to permission yet)

Comment: Python is installed by default on all Mac OS... Or at least I hope it is. Typing 'python' at terminal should launch it for you.

Comment: thnx,lol,didn't know that) u made my life easier :) terminal is soooo native for me ^_^

Comment: Absolutely. Not sure what your favorite IDE is, but the 'idle' command in terminal will launch a simple python editor for you to play with.

Comment: anyways, i did it in c gcc. once tested, will post.